# Evaluate $\int_{-\pi/4}^{\pi/4} \frac{x\sin(x)}{1+\exp(x^2\sin(x))} \mathrm{d}x$

Tags: integration

Can any one obtain an analytical expression for the area under the curve $$f(x)=\frac{x\sin(x)}{1+\exp(x^2\sin(x))}$$ from $x = -\frac{\pi}{4}$ to $x = \frac{\pi}{4}$, as I can't ! The numerical value is 0.15175. Any suggestions would be most welcome.

Comment: First, before anything, go here $\longrightarrow$ https://math.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/5020/mathjax-basic-tutorial-and-quick-reference

Comment: texed your question

Comment: And a heading like "Evaluate this integral" is better than "Innocent".

Comment: the result should be $$-\frac{\pi -4}{4 \sqrt{2}}$$

Comment: @Dr.SonnhardGraubner That doesn't really help, does it?

Comment: why not now he/she knows at least the result

Comment: @Dr.SonnhardGraubner He **already** knows the result. To make it "exact" doesn't seem to add anything helpful to the OP's question...

Comment: The result I quoted was by numerical integration as I could not find a closed form solution.

Answer (score 6):

Just observe the symmetry:
$$\int_{ - \pi /4}^{\pi /4} {\frac{{x\sin x}}{{1 + {e^{{x^2}\sin x}}}}dx}  = \int_0^{\pi /4} {\left( {\frac{{x\sin x}}{{1 + {e^{{x^2}\sin x}}}} + \frac{{x\sin x}}{{1 + {e^{ - {x^2}\sin x}}}}} \right)dx}  = \int_0^{\pi /4} {x\sin xdx}  = \frac{{4 - \pi }}{{4\sqrt 2 }}$$

Comment: pretty...(+1)!!!

Comment: Very nice ! $\to +1$

Answer (score 1):

I don't know how the antiderivative could be obtained the CAS I used did not give anything even using special functions).

However, over the given range, the integrand can be quite nicely represented using Padé approximants. For example
$$f(x)\approx\frac{\frac{x^2}{2}-\frac{65 x^3}{8407}+\frac{1399 x^4}{16814}-\frac{25091
   x^5}{100884}-\frac{119389 x^6}{6053040} }{1-\frac{130 x}{8407}+\frac{16801 x^2}{50442} }$$ would lead to an explicit expression which evaluates as $0.151743$.

Using $[n,2]$ Padé approximants, the following numerical values are obtained
$$\left(
\begin{array}{cc}
 n & \text{integral} \\
 4 & 0.158864 \\
 5 & 0.151865 \\
 6 & 0.151743 \\
 7 & 0.151746 \\
 8 & 0.151746 \\
 9 & 0.151747 \\
 10 & 0.151746
\end{array}
\right)$$

Simpler would be a Taylor expansion of the integrand
$$f(x)=\frac{x^2}{2}-\frac{x^4}{12}-\frac{x^5}{4}+\frac{x^6}{240}+\frac{x^7}{12}-\frac{x
   ^8}{10080}-\frac{x^9}{90}+\frac{x^{10}}{725760}+\frac{109
   x^{11}}{5040}+O\left(x^{12}\right)$$ which leads to
$$I=\frac{\pi ^3}{192}-\frac{\pi ^5}{30720}+\frac{\pi ^7}{13762560}-\frac{\pi
   ^9}{11890851840}+\frac{\pi ^{11}}{16742319390720}\approx 0.151746414000$$ while the given solution is $\approx 0.151746413917$.

Comment: I note your point and accept that there may not be a closed form solution. However, I am optimistic. Your approach is very interesting. It has been many years since I did Pade approximations, I can tell !

Comment: @Callie12. You also could use Taylor series and (for sure) get the same result for an expansion to the $10^{th}$ order. This would be simpler.